# PowerPoint 365 - Video will not replay when slideshow access it second time

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm putting together a PowerPoint slide show that will include some video and some static slides. I'm building a "control slide" so I can have a "home" place to start from and then go to different parts of the deck, return back "home," go somewhere else, go back, etc. I realize I can also use the PowerPoint Zoom feature for this and I will, but that doesn't help with the problem I'll describe below.

Most of the time I want a linked video to run in a continuous loop, in a window on one of the slides. When I hit a "Home" button I want it to stop and for the show to go to the control slide. Then I select the next place I want to go. When I'm done there, I press a Home button on that slide and am returned. Then I click the video-slide link and it is supposed to start playing again, but it doesn't.

I put together a test deck to illustrate but cannot find an "attach files" button here ... if someone will tell me how to do that I will attach it.

I start the show and the control slide displays. All good.

I click the link to the slide containing the video. The show jumps to that slide and the video plays in a loop, like I've set it up to do. All good.

Then I click a Home button at top right of the slide and that returns me to the control slide. All good.

Here's the problem. If I click the video a second time, its slide displays but the video will not play automatically. I have to click the video to get it to play again.

Is this a PowerPoint limitation, or have I not yet figured out how to make the video play the second and subsequent times I tell the show to go to its slide?

Comment: review this: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/set-the-play-options-for-a-video-in-your-presentation-f0d5b3f1-37ba-4a0d-9d94-f8e33cef29bf]{https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/set-the-play-options-for-a-video-in-your-presentation-f0d5b3f1-37ba-4a0d-9d94-f8e33cef29bf}

Comment: That page doesn't address behavior if one returns to a slide after playing the video on it a first time. They control whether the video auto-rewinds after playing and whether you can make it play continuously. I've already set both of those, and neither addresses the behavior I'm describing.  The video plays automatically the first time through; from then on I have to click the video itself if I return to the slide.  PowerPoint seems to think, "he's already auto-played the video on this slide, so it's obvious that he wouldn't want to auto-play it again if he returns to it." Except I do.

Comment: The page however does state the conditions under which the video should play and you should be able to determine where you video falls based on the setting you configured it. Unfortunately, short of absently guessing things, further troubleshooting really requires access to the PPTX that is problematic (or if you don't want to post the original, create a second one that behaves the same way and post it).

Comment: From my original post: 

"I put together a test deck to illustrate but cannot find an 'attach files' button here ... if someone will tell me how to do that I will attach it."

How do I attach a file to this question? I still don't see a way to do that.

And ... the video does play automatically the first time I click to the slide where it is linked. It does NOT play automatically on successive clicks to that slide. That's the problem I can't figure out how to solve, and the URL you pointed me to doesn't speak to returning again to a video that is set to play automatically.

Comment: This site does not have a built-in file attachment. You need to upload to to a host and then share the file and provide us with the shared link. There are many options out there including box, onedrive, google, ...